# Submit button is not submitting the form after changing the button type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

After changing my button `type` to `submit` it's not submitting the form. Somehow, the AJAX request is not working after that. If I change it to `type="button"` then it's working, but  I want this because **required** validation is not working while giving `type="button"`. It only works when I'm giving **button type submit** but then the form is not submitting.

```html
<form>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="passwordReset" placeholder="Email" required/>
  <button type="submit" id="passwordButton"> Submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
$("#passwordButton").on('submit', function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  const email = $("#passwordReset").val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/forget_password=" + email,
    success: function(response) {
      if (!response.data) {
        $(".sendError").show();
      } else {
        $(".sendSuccess").show();
      }
    }
  });
})
```

I want my form to be submitted while checking the `required` condition also.

Comment: The submit *button* does not have a `submit` method - the *form* does - change your event to `$("form").on("submit"...`

Comment: Use `submit` event on `form`.  You can use as @freedomn-m mentioned or if you have multiple form on same page, then give ID to `form` and use `submit` event on `form` using ID.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from MDN:

> Note that the submit event fires on the  element itself, and not on any  or  inside it. (Forms are submitted, not buttons.)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event

Attach the listener to the `click` even of the button, or to the `submit` event of the form.

Comment: @InsaneDA — Your edit fails to address the point raised in the two answers and the comment.

Answer (score 1):

[HTMLFormElement: submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event)

> Note that the submit event fires on the `<form>` element itself, and not on any `<button>` or `<input type="submit">` inside it. (Forms are submitted, not buttons.)

Try [**`click`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) event instead:

```
$("#passwordButton").on('click', function(e) {
```

**Update:** I think simply *submit* event on the *form* is enough here as the event will fire on clicking any input `type=submit`:

```js
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(){
  alert('Your form is submitting');
  /*
    Your code here
  */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="passwordReset" placeholder="Email" required/>
  <button type="submit" id="passwordButton"> Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: if i use click then html valiation `required` is not working

Comment: @InsaneDA, I think you can use `submit` event on the `form` element. Please check the updated answer:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just create a normal like `<button onclick="Submit()">save</button>`
and write Code like that:

```
Submit(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  const email = $("#passwordReset").val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/forget_password=" + email,
    success: function(response) {
      if (!response.data) {
        $(".sendError").show();
      } else {
        $(".sendSuccess").show();
      }
    }
  });
})
}
```

Comment: Don't use this approach. It's a big step backwards over what the OP is already doing.

Comment: @Rary McCrossan I couldn't understand what  would you like to say

Comment: Don't use `onclick` attributes, or any other inline `on[event]` attributes. They are outdated and bad practice. Use unobtrusive event handlers, as the OP is already doing. In addition, in this case you should be using the `submit` event, not the `click` event.

Answer (score 0):

Add Id or class attribute to your form.

```
<form id="formYouWantToSubmit">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="passwordReset" placeholder="Email" required/>
    <button type="submit" id="passwordButton"> Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then,

```
$("#formYouWantToSubmit").on('submit', function(e) { 
    const email = $("#passwordReset").val();

    // This will validate if email having any value (from string point of view)
    if (!email) {
        e.preventDefault();// To restrict form submission
        //### Do anything here when validation fails
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/forget_password=" + email,
            success: function(response) {

            if (!response.data) {
                $(".sendError").show();
            } else {
                $(".sendSuccess").show();
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Things to remember:

- button type submit will ultimately submits the form to current page (due to action attribute is missing)
- When we user Ajax to do something we ultimately seek a 'page-load-less' activity. In your case you are doing both submitting the form using submit button and making Ajax request, which will hard to get executed and if any chance it gets executed you won't be able witness any 'success' or 'error' activities because until then page already been reloaded.